# Requesting definitive way to make JQM format pages loaded via h ref b/c nothing works

Tags: jquery-mobile

So I have a page which uses an index.php file to dispatch pages using mod_rewrite.  So something like /bills/list is rewritten as index.php?display=bills&category=lists.  Works wonderfully, when I tag everything with data-ajax='false'.  The nav menu and every link i referenced using a basic a href tag - [Bills](/bills/list) and so on.

Of course the problem I have and which has not been answered after two days of messing around with it, is that when a link is clicked, the stylesheets are not loaded.  I get why and I get how jqm works, swapping out the dom and all that.

Question is, how do I get my style sheets to format the new page when it is called up?

Here's what I have tried so far - 
    $(document).on('pageload', function(event, ui){
    //  alert('page just shown');

```
    //$('#pals_Committee').listview('refresh');
//  $("#page").trigger("pagecreate");
//  $('ul').listview('refresh');
//  $( "div[data-role=page]" ).refresh();
//page( "destroy" ).page(); 

//  get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
//              $('#contentDiv').html(data).page();    
//  $('#pals_Committee').trigger("create");
//  $('#pals_Committee').page('destroy').page();
//  $('#pals_Committee div[data-role="content"]').html(content);

    //$.mobile.changePage("#pageId");
    //$(document).listview('refresh');
});
```

So far the only thing that works is the alert.  And note I've tried this all in pagecreate, pageinit, and pageload.  Really don't get why this is so difficult, it seems like someone somewhere would have posted a solution...the best I can find are random fringe cases that don't really apply.

Thanks to user3023313, who get me to realize that any scripts need to be in the body.

Answer (score 0):

All scripts should be in all html pages.

The JQM event cycle (pagecreate/beforeshow/show/foo) works when you use JQM navigation. You keep your first page DOM and shuffle pages in and out of it.

By setting `data-ajax=false`you disable JQM nav and do a classic link from a to b, b maybe b-eing `index.php/foo/bar`. This should reload ypur index page afresh and if all your CSS/JS files are there you should not have to call anything.

If you are going to a new page, say `foo.php/baz/bam` with JQM nav swirched off, the new page also needs all CSS/JS and should also init without any specific call.

You can use Firequery in Firebug to see if JQM widgets are set.

If that does not solve it, please provide your page structure and navigation code.

Comment: Thanks for reply!  I am using data-ajax='false' but that of course slows things down & I lose the neat transitions.  I figure that using simple links should be easy enough - jqm's manual says that new pages are parsed from the data-role=page, then swapped into  dom. I get that, just don't get how to apply formatting - there should be a simple method, no? And also since the pages are dynamically created, I won't know the id for the data-role page, so that seems to be a problem as well.  Page Code: http://pastebin.com/YZWidUEx  Final.js (called inside body):  http://pastebin.com/8HRFLPQj

Comment: `data-ajax="false"` means all pages will be loaded standalone. It won't necessarily be slower, because the browser probably caches JS/CSS. Normal JQM loads first page, then appends `"div-data-role-page"` to the initial page DOM(!) - this way transitions are possible. Also when doing so, pages should automatically be enhanced by JQM. Let me check your code to see why it's not applied. Easy way to test is the [JQM JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ofuhaw/167/edit). I usually just paste there and play around.

Comment: not sure but `rel="Stylesheet"` should probably have no caps and I always add `type="text/javascript"` to all JS files. Also, try the JQM method `enhanceWithin()` to enhance stuff within a container, eg. `$(document).enhanceWithin()`. Does that help?

Comment: Yeah I'm looking for a way to not use data-ajax = false.  Is there a method or something to render an html code block with a style sheet?